# is it possible to send the reports via email that is available in contact object emails

Tags: apex, reporting

i need to send the reports to contact email as an attachment in every week.
it is possible to send the reports to users mail id but how to achieve this problem.
 i don't know how to retrieve the reports based on the contact can anyone suggest me a good solution

Answer (score 0):

To send report via email, there are 2 options (User or public group). If you want to send the report to contact you can write apex class to run report. Schedule the apex class and send the data from report to the contact. [apex report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_intro.htm)